# Windows lockout event (4740) with mutilpe domain controllers

Tags: event-log, windows-server

If I have two DC's on a network and a user is locked out on Srv2 (event 4740), can this event get propagated to Srv1's eventlog aswell or are there settings to control this?

I am hoping it is possible to check only one event log to read all lockout events for an entire domain. From what I have been able to deduce it appears that evt 4740 only appears on the server where the lockout actually occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event forwarding, forwards events from one computer to another. This can be used in order to collect events at a specific computer to ease eventlog-handling.

Microsoft has a technet article for this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx

Windows IT-pro also has an article regarding troubleshooting eventlog forwarding:

http://windowsitpro.com/security/q-what-are-some-simple-tips-testing-and-troubleshooting-windows-event-forwarding-and-collec

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dabbled with AD in a couple of years, but I believe that the lockout will happen on one controller, and then will the other DCs receive data through the synchronizations but not log that lockout. It might be in the sync logs, but most likely not.

You didn't say if you have Read-only-DCs, but I suspect you don't.

I think you must read all event logs of the DCs you have. You might want to consider something like 'Splunk' etc. I remember it being used in a company I worked in 3 years ago. However, I'm in no way affiliated with 'splunk' and I don't know it well enough to advocate it in any way.

Comment: There are no read only DC's. I know there are settings in GPO to select what gets logged in the event log and to control what get's synced between DC's but have been unable to find anything specifically for this event. I'm hoping that someone else knows a technique because there may be a large number of DC's so I don't want to software running on each or having to iterate through them all.

Comment: What OS runs the DCs?

Event forwarding is a new Server 2008 feature that allows events to be forwarded from one Server 2008 computer to another over the HTTP protocol. The advantage of this is that you can set up the equivalent of a log collection server, so rather than having to check the event logs of each computer on the network for specific events, you can check for events from many computers in a single place.

Comment: Ah, that may be just what I was looking for!   I believe that some events are synced between DC's - do you perhaps know where I can find info on that, specifically wrt event 4740?

Comment: I've come up with an 'answer' suggestion, if you don't mind you might want to 'accept' it.